# Cannot set value from sqlite to spinners?

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

Here is my requirement am having sqlite db am getting json response from server and saving it and setting that value to spinner its working fine but when i edit listview i need to edit the value of spinner set that value to spinners but not getting that i have tried everything let me post what i have tried so far:
This is the adapter where am trying to set the spinners:

```
 final ArrayList<Model_Account> arrayobj = new ArrayList<Model_Account>();
            spinners_state_db = new Spinners_DB_State(getBaseContext());
            final Spinner_DB_AccountManagers acmobj = new Spinner_DB_AccountManagers(getBaseContext());
```

This where am setting selection value to spinners:

```
 modelobj.setName(((edit_accnt.getString(edit_accnt.getColumnIndex(Model_Account.State)))));
                    int position=0;
                    position=spinner_state_Adapter.getPosition(modelobj);
                    spinner_state.setSelection(position);
```

Always getting position -1 don't know where am making mistake am using material spinner!!

My spinner Classs:

```
public class Spinners_DB_State extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "spinners.db";


    public Spinners_DB_State(android.content.Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                String Create_Spinner= " CREATE TABLE "  + Model_Account.Spinner_Table + "("
                        + Model_Account.spinners_id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
                        + Model_Account.StateName + " TEXT ,"
                        + Model_Account.PairlinkID + " INTEGER ,"
                        + Model_Account.Spinner_AccountManager + "INTEGER ,"
                        + Model_Account.UserID + " INTEGER "
                        + ");";
                    db.execSQL(Create_Spinner);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Model_Account.Spinner_Table);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public void InsertName(Model_Account modlobj){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentobj = new ContentValues();
        contentobj.put(Model_Account.StateName,modlobj.getName());
        contentobj.put(Model_Account.PairlinkID, modlobj.getStateid());
        db.insert(Model_Account.Spinner_Table, null, contentobj);
        db.close();
    }

    public List<Spinner_id> list() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Model_Account.Spinner_Table;
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        List<Spinner_id> listobj = new ArrayList<Spinner_id>();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Model_Account modelobj = new Model_Account();
                modelobj.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Model_Account.StateName)));
                modelobj.setStateid(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Model_Account.PairlinkID)));
                listobj.add(modelobj);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }db.close();
        return listobj;


    }
    public void update(Model_Account modlobj){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentobj=new ContentValues();
        contentobj.put(Model_Account.StateName,modlobj.getName());
        contentobj.put(Model_Account.PairlinkID, modlobj.getStateid());
        db.update(Model_Account.Spinner_Table,contentobj,Model_Account.PairlinkID+ "= ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(modlobj.getStateid())});
        db.close();
}
    public Cursor getData(Model_Account id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from " + Model_Account.Spinner_Table + " where " +  Model_Account.PairlinkID  + " = "  +  id.getStateid()  +"", null );
        return res;
    }
    public void StateInsertorUpdate(Model_Account modlobj){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query=" SELECT  * FROM " + Model_Account.Spinner_Table+ " WHERE " + Model_Account.PairlinkID +  "  =" +  modlobj.getStateid() +"";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            update(modlobj);
        } else {
           InsertName(modlobj);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your dbclass?

Comment: check the edit @NiteshKumar